# How to get keystore file from Google Play to sign my app to publish

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-app-signing

I have implemented map in my app, during development it is working fine but after publishing this app map is not working.

I have searched over Internet to solve this problem and I found solution as follows: build a signed apk by using existing keystore which can be found by Google Play where I have created a project to publish my app on Google Play store.

playstore file might be here (google play):
[image: playstore file might be here (google play)]

Problem is when I am downloading this certificate as shown in above attachment, I am getting file name called *deployment_cret.der*.
 I am getting very confused here to use downloaded file as keystore

is it a configuration file if yes, how to configure it

Is there any other way to do this

I am really very confused about it,
how to build a signed apk where App Signing is enabled on Google Play

Answer (score 3):

If the I am not wrong, you are trying to say that your map functionality was working fine in development but not working with release apk ? If this is so then follow these steps :

1. Create fingerprint (SHA1) through your keystore file through this command :

> keytool -list -v -keystore /YOUR_KEYSTORE_PATH/YOUR_KEYSTORE.jks
>   -alias YOUR_KEYSTORE_ALIAS

You need to navigate first to your systems /jre/bin which is used in android studio, in my case its android studio's built in jre, so it was in Android Studio/jre/bin

By running this command you will get an SHA1 for keystore, copy that

2. Now go to google developer console and create a new cliet ID for this SHA1
3. On google developer console, create a new API key

> Credentials -> Create Credentials -> API key -> Restrict Key -> Android Apps

and enter your fingerprint here and save.

Now you will be able to use this API key in your google_maps_api.xml for both debug and release.

Let me know through comments on this question if you have any confusion/concern.

Comment: yes you are right #Araju

I have already used this solution  but not working